# Magento layered navigation Size not pulling in correctly

Tags: magento, navigation

The problem we are having is as follows.

We have a configurable->simple product relationship set up so that you can select a size of a shirt you want to buy. The configurable products are Enabled and visible in Catalog,Search. The simple ones are tied to the parent configurable product with differencing sizes (M, L, XL, etc.) and are Enabled, Not Visible Individually.

We originally imported this data from different database. It appears everything in Magento is setup correctly, but the number of products for Sizes are not correct in layered navigation.

What does seem to fix the totals is **resaving** the simple product. But we can't do that for all 6000+ products. Any ideas? Is there a mysql table that we are missing that should have data?
 We've cleared indexes multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reindexing `Product Attributes` should do the trick. Are you sure it executes without an error? You can also try running it from command line.

Comment: It does execute, but still no avail.